# How to test field visibility with Capybara?

Tags: rspec, capybara

Note:  This question is about using Capybara 1.1.2, not current versions.

I have a hidden text field, and a button which make it visible.

hidden text field:

```
<input type="text" name="Franchise Name" id="new_franchise_name" placeholder="Franchise Name" style="display:none;" />
```

button and js event handler which makes the the above field visible:

```
<button class="btn btn-medium" id="create_franchise" data-remote="true" >Create New Franchise</button>

$('#create_franchise').click(function(){
  $('#new_franchise_name').css('display', 'inline-block');
}
```

In my test, I have the following:

```
page.all('#new_franchise_name') #=> returns array with text input
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true
page.all('#new_franchise_name') #=> returns empty array as expected
page.find_button('Create New Franchise').click #=> sets the input css "display:inline-block"
page.all('#new_franchise_name') #=> still returns empty array. Should include the text field
```

I've explored a few other methods but this seems to be the most straight-forward... except that it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This answer is for current (2.14.3 currently) releases of Capybara.  It only came out after discussion that the OP is using Capybara 1.1.2 where behavior was significantly different**

A couple of things

1. If you're testing an app, never change Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements (just leave it at the default of true), use the `visible` option on the queries where you want Capybara to "see" non-visible elements. `page.find('#new_franchise_name', visible: :all)`
2. Stay away from `all` in favor of `find` when you want a single element (which anything with an id should be).  `all` has a number of shortcomings, not the least of which is that it won't wait for elements to appear unless you pass one of the count options. (`first` has the same shortcomings)
3. When testing use the assertions/expectations rather than `find` when you don't need the element for anything else

Taking these into account your test should be written as

```
expect(page).not_to have_css('#new_franchise_name')  # or  .to have_no_css(...)
page.click_button('Create New Franchise')
expect(page).to have_css('#new_franchise_name')
```

If for some reason you have changed the default setting of `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements` to false then the test could be written as

```
expect(page).not_to have_css('#new_franchise_name', visible: true)  # or  .to have_no_css(...)
page.click_button('Create New Franchise')
expect(page).to have_css('#new_franchise_name', visible: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Very helpful advice indeed. The problem is that this wouldn't solve the problem I'm having because these expects don't test for the elements visibility. The `input#new_franchise_name` exists with or without clicking the button. I'm also getting the following error: `RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected css "#new_franchise_name" not to return anything` when those expect methods should return a boolean. Any suggestions

Comment: @JesseNovotny  Expectations don't return booleans - they either succeed or raise an error, which is generally what is wanted in tests.  It sounds like you already have set `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false` somewhere which is a terrible idea to do when writing tests (ok for automation though) since it means you're no longer testing what a user would be able to see/do.  I'm going to update the answer to specify the visibility required, but the better solution is to stop changing the default of ignore_hidden_elements

Comment: Thanks! That rocks. My understanding is that `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements` is false by default. It's currently returning false and I've only ever set it to try while in pry.

Comment: @JesseNovotny If you do actually need boolean responses then you would use `page.has_css?(...)` instead, but if writing tests there are VERY few times when you want a boolean response instead of a test failure.

Comment: @JesseNovotny What version of Capybara are you using -- it's defaulted to true since v2.1 (4 years ago) https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/History.md#version-210 -  set here - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara.rb#L460

Comment: I'm working on a massive legacy code base... sadly, we're working with v1.1.2. Also, I'm still running into the original problem. Clicking the button doesn't change the input's visibility as far as Capybara can tell even though I know it work.

Comment: @JesseNovotny Oh, and to clarify the tests as originally written in the answer do test for visibility when `ignore_hidden_elements` has the default value of `true` because at that point it doesn't matter if the element is not in the page, or in the page but not visible since it will pass `not_to have_css`.    That way it doesn't matter whether your code makes it visible, dynamically creates it, or loads it via ajax and displays it, the test wouldn't have to change since the overall behavior from the users perspective hasn't changed either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147498/discussion-between-jesse-novotny-and-thomas-walpole).

Comment: @JesseNovotny UHHH -- 1.1.2???? at the very least you should update to 1.1.4 which fixes some race conditions and was the last 1.x release, but really you should take the time to update to the 2.x branch, 1.x is obsolete